# Free alternative to SVNKit?

Tags: gratis, library, java, subversion

I'm looking for an alternative to SVNKit that has a license more like Apache or BSD, i.e. a license that does not require me to release the source code of my own Java program that is using the SVN lib.

It should be a pure Java implementation to make distribution a bit easier.

Please provide your own experience with your suggested alternative -- if you have some.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794157/svnkit-alternative